# Regularly refresh Auth0 token in auth0-spa-js

Tags: reactjs, auth0

Within React, I want to check every 15 minutes for whether the current session token is valid and, if not, refresh it. Here's what I'm trying so far:

```
  const refreshToken = async () => {
    console.log(':: refreshToken');
    const isAuthenticated = await auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
    const token = await auth0Client.getTokenSilently();

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const claims = await auth0Client.getIdTokenClaims();
      const claimsDecoded = await jwt_decode(claims.__raw);
      console.log(claimsDecoded.exp);

      dispatch({
        type: 'REFRESH_TOKEN',
        payload: {
          user: {
            token: token,
            expires: claimsDecoded.exp,
            claims: claims.__raw
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      logout();
    }
  };

  // Continually refresh Auth0 session
  useEffect(() => {
    const delay = 900000; // 15m
    const timer = setInterval(async () => {
      console.log(':: Session refresh');
      if (state.isAuthenticated) {
        await refreshToken();
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [refreshToken, state.isAuthenticated]);
```

The issue I'm seeing is that, even though this runs every 15 minutes, `console.log(claimsDecoded.exp)` still always shows the same expiration timestamp from the retrieved token. And, once that expiration happens, the application starts to fail auth to the API due to the token being sent to the API is expired. So it is as if the token never did get refreshed.

I've had to rethink how this all works as I try to move to the latest (2.0.0) release of `auth0-spa-js`.

I've tried using the `checkSession()` function as well, and that hasn't seemed to make a difference.

Comment: More context: Previous to v2.0.0, I was using the `localOnly` feature, which would require the user to login again to the application, but would not log the user out of Auth0. This feature seems to now be gone in v2.0.0, so I figured an automatic refresh would work.

Comment: I can get around my original issue (the upgrade to v2) with the `localOnly` change noted here: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md#localonly-logout-has-been-removed-and-replaced-by-onredirect

I just wonder if this is still the best way to refresh the user's session.